# Non-ephemeral Google Cloud Shell with Custom Container Image?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

Is it possible to use Google Cloud Shell with a [custom container image](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/customizing-container-image) and have a persistent `$HOME`, like it is without a custom image? (Disabling *Ephemeral Mode* from the UI re-launches it without the custom image.)

Comment: can you please clarify your setup? Was Ephemeral mode enabled when you used the custom image, then once you disabled it you go back to the base image? Also, what is your use case when you encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible today: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/open-in-cloud-shell

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.